# How to pass a variable to an include in a Nunjucks macro

Tags: macros, gulp, include, frontend, nunjucks

I am making a repeatable card that has several text variables but also two variable icons that are SVGs. I want to make the SVG icons variables within the macro but i get a Gulp error

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ Template render error: (unknown path)   Template render error: (C:...\frontend\dev\templates\partials\modules_activity-overview.njk)
>   Error: template not found:  {{ icon }}

I can use includes in the macro just fine but i can't seem to make the value of the include a variable.

My macro looks like this:

```
{% macro activityCard(icon='partials/svg/alarm.svg', name, atime, type, event, message) %}
<div class="activity-tile">
    <div  class="activity-tile__icon">{% include " {{ icon }} " %}</div>
    <div>
        <h2>{{ name }}</h2>
        <time>{{ atime }}</time>
        <div class="activity-tile__details">
            <span><em>Type</em>{{ type }}</span>
            <span><em>Event</em>{{ event }}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="activity-tile__weather">
            <i>{% include "partials/svg/weather.svg" %}</i>
            <span>{{ message }}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endmacro %}
```

And i am calling it in my page like this:

```
{% import 'macros/activity-card-macro.njk' as acard %}
{{ acard.activityCard('partials/svg/alarm.svg', 'Main Office', '12/18/2017 11:58 PM EST', 'Missing open', 'Opened late', '') }}
```

What is the proper syntax to make an variable in an include in a macro?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `{% include "{{icon}}" %}` instead `{{icon}}`?

Comment: Because it outputs the SVG path as text but doesn't insert it as an include.

Comment: Try `{% include icon %}` :)

Comment: That worked but it has some quarks.
1. If my macro has multiple variables, then the SVG includes must be listed last. (I can live with this!)
2. I cannot pass an empty string because it causes the include to fail. That makes sense. But sometimes i need the macro to include an icon and sometime i don't. Any clever solution for this?